# Find and replace with sed, keep original line too

Tags: linux, command-line, regex, sed

I have

```
param1='123'
```

I would like

```
param1='123'
param2=123
```

where 123 will change between the files I'd like to run this on.

I can get param2 using `sed -i "s/param1=\([0-9]\+\)/param2='\1'/g" '{}' \;`
But then I will lose param1.

I can also append line param2 using `sed -i "param1='\([0-9]\+\)';/a \param2=\1;` but the pattern isn't recognised and i end up with `param2=1`

Is there a way to combine these two commands, or another way of working this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the entire match as well as the number group and then specify both in the output:

```
echo "param1='123'" | sed "s/\(param1='\([0-9]\+\)'\)/\1\nparam2=\2/g"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Are you outputting the entire match, then adding a newline with `nparam2` and then outputting the second match? Or how does this work?

Comment: @user1792403: Yes, that is it. Please note that `\1` can be replaced by `&` (entire matched string) and the outer `\(` and `\)` can be removed. --- Also the `g` flag at the end is superfluous as the substitution will most probably not work with multiple matches on a single line as wanted. --- Please not that not all implementations of `sed` support `\n` for inserting newline. GNU sed supports it.

Comment: When i have enough reputation points I will come back to +1 this comment, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some more options:

1. Perl

   ```
   echo "param1='123'" | perl -lpe 'print; s/(.+=).(\d+)./$1$2/'
   ```
2. `awk`

   ```
   echo "param1='123'" | awk -F"[ =']" '{print $0"\n"$1"="$3}'
   ```
3. shell

   ```
   echo "param1='123'" | while read l; do echo "$l"; echo "${l//\'/}"; done
   ```
4. A simpler `sed`

   ```
   echo "param1='123'" | sed "p;s/'//g"
   ```

Comment: Nice answer! I’m just wondering why the tool chosen by OP (sed) is listed as the last one. Moreover when its command is the simplest and shortest one…

Comment: @Melebius because when I posted this there was already another `sed` answer, so I gave other choices. Also, while the `sed` is the shortest, it is also the mot cryptic.